# Auto re-size in Div not working

Tags: html, css

I have a `<div>` called `"bottom"` which holds 2 `divs` together. The 2 `divs` inside are `"manufacturers"` and `"main"` which are located side by side with each other. What I want is that the `<div id="bottom">` must be auto resizable when either the two divisions expands (the `<div id="main">` lists down all the available products that is why it also has an auto height). The problem is that when I use a `float` property or a `"display: inline"` property in the `main` and `manufacturers` divs it overrides the `bottom` div causing it not to expand.

here's my css code:

```
#bottom{
    padding: 1.5em;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 3.7em;
    margin-bottom: 5em;
    background-color: white;
    width: 67em;
    height: auto;
}
#manufacturers{
    padding: 1em;
    width: 13em;
    height: auto;
    border: 1px solid #CFCFCF;
    font-size: 17px;
    float: left;
}
#main{
    float: right;
    padding: 0.5em;
    width: 47em;
    height: 10em;
    background: blue;
    position: relative;
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: You should define the width in percentage...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case element with ID "bottom" collapsed because of elements inside have floats (left or right). You should use clearfix class with #bottom:

```
.clearfix: before,
.clearfix: after {
    display: table;
    content: " "
}
.clearfix: after {
    clear: both
}
```

Answer to question about ["clearfix"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-clearfix)

Answer (score 0):

```
#main{
display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try this:

```
#bottom{
    width: 100%;
}
#manufacturers{
    width: 50%;
}
#main{
    width: 50%;
}
```

Add above css properties in your existing CSS stylesheet. Apart from it:

Expanding Downward to fit the content is the expected behavior. If you have specified floats somewhere in your style you may need to clear them.

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

Comment: my problem is that the `bottom div` which holds the 2 divs ('manufacturers' on left and `main` on right) does not expands downward. It must auto resize downward. I have no problem in its width, only with the height which must be auto resizeable once the products gets populated downward

Comment: Expanding Downward to fit the content is the expected behavior. If you have specified floats somewhere in your css you may need to clear them.

Comment: @user3819129 Updated my answer, you could try this. You need to clear your floats in your HTML.